# Can I mount Google cloud storage bucket to a pod as a persistent disk. If yes how?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a gke cluster with nodes in 3 different Zones but same region. I want to use persistent disks to my pods. But the pods are created randomly in all the 3 zones.How can I use a gcePD (common for all the nodes). or Can I add the storage bucket in the pod deployment (Yaml) file. If it is podssible .kindly suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried mounting the Google Cloud storage bucket using the [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)?. I also find similar [queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966832/mount-google-storage-bucket-in-google-container) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587737/can-i-mount-a-gcs-bucket-inside-kubernetes-pod) in the community, which says its possible. See if that helps you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow this github link. You need to install fuse in the image. Your container should be in previliged mode and you need to use lifecycle.
https://github.com/maciekrb/gcs-fuse-sample